PVLIB fit Sandia module function - TypeError: expected 1D vector for x when calling polyfit
I'm trying to use pvlib.inverter.fit_sandia to evaluate the coefficients for the Sandia inverter model
Pac0 = 330*1000
Pnt = 20
sandia_params  = pvlib.inverter.fit_sandia(ac_power,
                                           dc_power,
                                           dc_voltage,
                                           dc_voltage_level,
                                           Pac0, Pnt)

ac_power, dc_power, are float64 arrays with 18 elements
dc_voltage is an array of 18 int64 elements
dc_voltage_level is a list of 18 strings with values that are either 'Vmin', 'Vnom' or 'Vmax' as specified in the documentation.
In particular, dc_voltage_level is
 ['Vmax', 'Vmax', 'Vmax', 'Vmax', 'Vmax', 'Vmax', 
  'Vnom', 'Vnom', 'Vnom', 'Vnom','Vnom', 'Vnom',
  'Vmin', 'Vmin', 'Vmin', 'Vmin', 'Vmin', 'Vmin']

I'm getting the following error:
d:\michele\documents modello-fisico\ plant 
simulation\inverter_data.py:67: RuntimeWarning: invalid value 
encountered in divide
ac_power_array / eff_array)
Traceback (most recent call last):

File D:\Michele\Documentsmodello-fisico\venv\lib\site- 
packages\spyder_kernels\customize\utils.py:209 in 
exec_encapsulate_locals
exec_fun(compile(code_ast, filename, "exec"), globals, None)

File d:\michele\documents\modello-fisico\gaibanella plant 
simulation\inverter_data.py:103
sandia_params  = pvlib.inverter.fit_sandia(ac_power,

File D:\Michele\Documents\modello-fisico\venv\lib\site- 
packages\pvlib\inverter.py:530 in fit_sandia
c, b, a = polyfit(x, y, 2)

File D:\Michele\Documents\modello-fisico\venv\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\polynomial\polynomial.py:1467 in polyfit
return pu._fit(polyvander, x, y, deg, rcond, full, w)

File D:\Michele\Documents\modello-fisico\venv\lib\site- 
packages\numpy\polynomial\polyutils.py:599 in _fit
raise TypeError("expected 1D vector for x")

TypeError: expected 1D vector for x

from this part of the function
for d in voltage_levels:
    x = dc_power[dc_voltage_level == d]
    y = ac_power[dc_voltage_level == d]
    # [2] STEP 3B
    print('x.shape returns:')
    print(x.shape)
    # fit a quadratic to (DC power, AC power)
    c, b, a = polyfit(x, y, 2)

Calling x.shape returns (0, 18)
The polyfit function is imported with
from numpy.polynomial.polynomial import polyfit  # different than np.polyfit

As I understand it x will always be a vector with as many dimensions as the number of points considered, which obviously has to be more than 1 to evaluate the inverter efficiency.
I'm not really sure if this is a misuse of the function by my side or maybe a bug. Any help would be appreciated.

The obvious debugging step is to print(x.shape) right before calling polyfit

And full error message.  You/we need to know whether the x it's complaining about is the same as the x in your call.

I've edited the question with those changes. I know it may be something very simple but I'm new to python and not really used to the environment so far..

dc_power is 2d, and x is 0 rows from that array. (0,18) is a 2d shape.

What's dc_power.shape? (18,) is 1d, (1,18) is 2d.  You may need to read more of the basic numpy introduction.
